# The Query subbmits but won't add to my database

Tags: php, mysqli

This query runs with no errors, but it doesn't add anything to the database i can't figure it out I've looked everywhere. What do you guys think? my Database connection is defined in another file and it works because other queries still work.

```
  function processs_form(){

            $clean_fullname = sanitize($_POST['fullname']);
            $clean_sport = sanitize($_POST['sport']);
            $clean_package = sanitize($_POST['package']);
            $clean_weight = sanitize($_POST['weight']);
            $clean_height = sanitize($_POST['height']);
            $clean_gpa = sanitize($_POST['GPA']);
            $clean_number = sanitize($_POST['number']);
            $clean_school = sanitize($_POST['school']);
            $clean_gradYear = sanitize($_POST['gradYear']);
            $clean_yearRecorded = sanitize($_POST['yearRecorded']);
            $clean_postion = sanitize($_POST['position']);
            $clean_info = sanitize($_POST['additioninfo']);
            $reply_value = 1;
            GLOBAL $mysqli;

            $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO video_tickets (`ticket_id`, `user_name`, `new_reply`, `full_name`, `sport`,
                    `position`, `year_recorded`, `grad_year`, `school`, `player_number`, `gpa`, `height`, `weight`,
                    `package`, `addition_info`) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

            $stmt->bind_param('isisssiisidddss', $loggedInUser->user_id, $loggedInUser->username, $reply_value,
                    $clean_fullname, $clean_sport , $clean_postion, 
                    $clean_yearRecorded, $grad_year, $clean_school, $clean_number, $clean_gpa, 
                    $clean_height, $clean_weight, $clean_package, $clean_info);
                $stmt->execute();
                $stmt->close();


            $message = <<<_HTML_

            Your Ticket Has Been submited You'll get a Reply within 24 Hours.


_HTML_;

            print nl2br(htmlentities($message));




}
```

Comment: you dont check to see if the db returns any errors

Comment: You have `$grad_year` but you're using `$clean_gradYear` most likely it. If one fails, they all fail.

Comment: absolutely important to good practices to check return results from prepare(), bind_param(), and execute().  Though honestly I just prefer coding to PDO, much nicer looking code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a great example of why it is important to check the return value of `prepare`, `execute`, `bind_param`, etc.

It's very likely that your query is in fact failing. It's likely in the `bind_param` phase, as others have pointed out - one of your parameters you are binding is uninitialized.

For example, [`execute()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php) returns back a `bool` to the caller indicating success or failure. You may check it as follows:

```
if (!$stmt->execute()) {
    echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
```

For a more complete guide: [PHP Prepared Statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: Possibly the best answer I've ever gotten thank you! apparently My LoggedinUser->user isn't working :/

Answer (score 1):

Your bind has `$grad_year` yet you're using `$clean_gradYear` as the variable in:

`$clean_gradYear = sanitize($_POST['gradYear']);`

Change `$grad_year` to `$clean_gradYear` in your bind_param value.

If one fails, your entire query will fail.

---

Error reporting would have signaled the error:

- **http://php.net/mysqli_error**